# Draw a parallel line with specific distance to already skewed line in canvas android

Tags: java, android, math

I have a Line(,) on canvas even it may be skewed, all i want to do is , to draw a new parallel line with respect to old Line(,) with equal Line Length.
Tried this one >>>>

```
    double d = getLength(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    double m = getSlope(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    double r = Math.sqrt(1 + Math.pow(m, 2));
    double endX = x + d / r;
    double endY = y + ((d * m) / r);
    return new double[]{x, y, endX, endY};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make parallel segment, you need to build perpendicular vector of needed length. 
Note that there are two solutions for both sided of segment

```
dx = x2 - x1
dy = y2 - y1
len = sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)
perpx = -dy * distance / len
perpy = dx * distance / len

// "left" line start
x1' = x1 + perpx
y1' = y1 + perpy
// "left" line end
x2' = x2 + perpx
y2' = y2 + perpy

// "right" line
x1'' = x1 - perpx
y1'' = y1 - perpy
x2'' = x2 - perpx
y2'' = y2 - perpy
```

Comment: working fine but distance between two line(parallel) isn't constant, any idea?

Comment: @Ashutosh Gupta Distance must be constant. Added more formulas to avoid confusion